# Getting same accuracy across different classifiers - sklearn

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, dataset, scikit-learn

I have a training set of 540 and testing set of 150 image pixels. The values are stored in different csv files as following:

```
[label],[num0],[num1],...,[num399]
```

The label is a single alphabet and the 400 nos are pixel values. This set is for sign language recognition.

Code -

```
import numpy as np 
import os
import csv
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn import cross_validation
from sklearn import linear_model

path = '/home/goel/skin'


X_train=[]
y_train=[]
X_test=[]
y_test=[]
ylist=[]

with open("20_20_centered_newer.csv",'r') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file,delimiter=',')
    reader.next()
    for row in file:
        y_train.append(row[0])
        if row[0] not in ylist:
            ylist.append(row[0])        
        row=row[2:]
        row=[int(x) for x in row.split(',')]
        X_train.append(np.array(row))

y2list=[]

with open("20x20_test.csv",'r') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file,delimiter=',')
    for row in file:
        y_test.append(row[0])
        if row[0] not in y2list:
            y2list.append(row[0])       
        row=row[2:]
        row=[int(x) for x in row.split(',')]
        X_test.append(np.array(row))

print ylist
print y2list

#clf = linear_model.SGDClassifier().fit(X_train,y_train)
#clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear').fit(X_train,y_train)
#clf = svm.LinearSVC().fit(X_train,y_train)
clf = linear_model.LogisticRegression().fit(X_train,y_train)
print clf.score(X_test,y_test)
```

Apparently, I am getting the same score of .78 across all the classifiers, upto 12 decimal places!!!

Is there a semantic error here that I don't know about?

Comment: The score is just the proportion of correctly labelled test samples (150*0.78 = 117 correct). The fact that the scores are the same to 12 decimal places is irrelevant. Is it plausible for the three classifiers to all get exactly 117/150 correct? Perhaps the remaining 33 test cases are much more difficult than the others. At the moment it's impossible to tell, since you haven't given us any input data.

Comment: Also check whether 117 of your 150 labels are the same. Then your classifiers might simply learn to always predict the most often occurring label, regardless of the input vector.

Comment: There are 2 labels in testing and 3 labels in training.
@user3760780 No, they are evenly distributed.

Comment: I trained with X_train having only those labels that are in y_test. Still getting the same score. Here are the files - https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B3JPglmAz1b5fk9MNU9ILXo2d2Z0V25Vc1dGRW9DVVd5NGhGQThOWW5pYklmRmtuRU1XeG8&usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably because I had too few classes to begin with. I repeated the experiment with 10 classes, and got a difference about 2% upon 5-fold cross-validation.